# Passing Context to helper class to display Toast at Try/Catch

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a JSON helper class. I have been trying to to display a Toast message if there was an error instead of just having it force closed. Problem is, since this is a helper class, it has no Context and cant display Toast. Can anyone please help steer me in the right direction on how to pass Context?

```
 public class JSONfunction {



public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url) {
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    JSONObject json = null;

    // HTTP Post
    try {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e("JSONfunction", "Error converting internet " + e.toString());
    }

    // Convert Response to String
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("JSONfunction", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    try {
        json = new JSONObject(result);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSONfunction", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return json;
}



public static JSONArray getJSONArray(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public static String getString(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
 }
```

Comment: You could remove the try/catch and make the function throw exceptions and then handle them in caller, then you wouldn't have to throw the context around for a function that, when performing as expected, does not need access to the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just added a Context to your method... `public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url, Context context) { Toast.makeText(context...);}` and then call it from an Activity or other context... From an activity: `getJSONfromURL(url, this);` since this will likely not be done an UIThread, then it'll be in a thread or AsyncTask, if that is inside an Activity, you can do this: `getJSONfromURL(url, MyHappyActivity.this);` Also, consider using the Application instead of the Activity... getApplicationContext() from an Activity will give you that context: `getJSONfromURL(url, getApplicationContext());` if called from within an Activity.

Comment: I'm sorry I just noticed I never accepted your answer as correct! Thanks for helping me last year lol